# Using Shiny Inputs to create new variables in the dataset

Tags: r, shiny

Say we have a little nfl player dataset:

```
      Team  POS  WT
1    Chiefs   K 175
2     Bills   K 225
3    Browns  CB 175
4  Chargers  DT 300
5    Browns  TE 220
6    Texans  LB 262
7   Cowboys  LB 234
8  Patriots  DT 309
9    Titans   K 218
10   Browns  WR 167
```

I want to create a shiny page that will let people put their own Weight (WT) in, and in the dataset it will create the difference between each nfl players weight and the input weight.

So far....nope.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(


titlePanel(h1("Which NFL Player Are You Most Like?", align = "center")),


sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(

  selectInput("team", "Choose a Team:", 
              choices = c("All","49ers","Bears","Bengals", "Bills", 
                          "Broncos","Browns","Buccaneers", "Cardinals",
                          "Charges","Cheifs","Colts", "Cowboys",
                          "Dolphins","Eagles","Falcons", "Giants",
                          "Jaguars","Jets","Lions", "Packers",
                          "Panthers","Patriots","Raiders", "Rams",
                          "Ravens","Redskins","Saints", "Seahawks",
                          "Steelers","Texans","Titans", "Vikings")),



  selectInput("Position", "What is your Football Position?:", 
              choices = c("All","C",  "CB", "DE", "DT", "FB", "G",  "K",  "LB", "LS", "NT", "P",  "QB", "RB",
                          "S",  "T",  "TE", "WR")),

  numericInput("Weight", "How Much Do You Weigh? (LBS):", NA)


),

mainPanel(
  p("Use the panel at the right to input your own information. Below will be the name or names of players you are most like. If you only want to use
    a subset of variables, leave the others blank or set to 'All'."),

#Right now I just want to know that it worked, so show me the updated dataset where there is   the Weight_diff column
  tableOutput("view")

  )
 )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
 NFLdat<-structure(list(Team = structure(c(10L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 30L, 12L, 
                              22L, 31L, 6L), .Label = c("49ers", "Bears", "Bengals", "Bills", 
                                                        "Broncos", "Browns", "Buccaneers", "Cardinals", "Chargers", "Chiefs", 
                                                        "Colts", "Cowboys", "Dolphins", "Eagles", "Falcons", "Giants", 
                                                        "Jaguars", "Jets", "Lions", "Packers", "Panthers", "Patriots", 
                                                        "Raiders", "Rams", "Ravens", "Redskins", "Saints", "Seahawks", 
                                                        "Steelers", "Texans", "Titans", "Vikings"), class = "factor"), 
           POS = structure(c(7L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 17L
           ), .Label = c("C", "CB", "DE", "DT", "FB", "G", "K", "LB", 
                         "LS", "NT", "P", "QB", "RB", "S", "T", "TE", "WR"), class = "factor"), 
           WT = c(175L, 225L, 175L, 300L, 220L, 262L, 234L, 309L, 218L, 
                  167L)), .Names = c("Team", "POS", "WT"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                         10L), class = "data.frame")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



observe({
 if(is.na(input$Weight)) NFLdat$Weight_diff<-abs(data$WT-data$WT)
 else NFLdat$Weight_diff<-abs(data$WT-((as.numeric(input$Weight))))
})


#Or alternatively
 inputWT <- reactive({
  input$Weight
 })

NFLdat$Weight_diff2<-abs(data$WT-inputWT)

output$view <- renderTable({
 NFLdat
}) 



output$new <-inputWT
})
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create a reactive expression that returns a `NFLdat` subset ready for rendering. I guess your shinyServer should be something along these lines:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 NFLdat.2show <- reactive({
     #browser()
     if (is.na(input$Weight)) return()

     bmask.team <- if (input$team!='All') NFLdat$Team==input$team else TRUE
     d <- NFLdat[bmask.team,]
     d$Weight_diff <- abs(d$WT-input$Weight)

     d
 })  

 output$view <- renderTable({
     NFLdat.2show()
 })

 })
```